# delete only key from an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hello I'm trying to delete only the keys from an array, I have this

```
{everyone: "everyone", random: "random", fast response time: "fast response time", less conversations: "less conversations"}
```

But I need this array in this way

```
["everyone", "random", "fast response time", "less conversations"]
```

I need only the values on this array, I have this code but it brings me an empty array

```
let array = {everyone: "everyone", random: "random", fast response time: "fast response time", less conversations: "less conversations"};
delete translation['everyone'];
delete translation['random'];
delete translation['fast response time'];
delete translation['less conversations'];
console.log(translation);
```

Comment: what's "translation"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object.values() will spit out the values in an array. Also your keys with spaces need to be quoted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

```js
const test = {
  everyone: "everyone",
  random: "random",
  "fast response time": "fast response time",
  "less conversations": "less conversations"
}

console.log(Object.values(test));
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been looking foor, thank you so much